# Intent not set,null return

Tags: android, android-intent

(Machine translation)
i use this code for start a vpn service.
The code first checks the username and password values are not empty, then the VPN service runs
My problem is that intent not set.
in debugger value of intent is null
where is the problem?

```
OnCheckedChangeListener connect=new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1)
    {
        str_user=User.getText().toString();
        str_pass=Pass.getText().toString();

        if(str_user.matches(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please inter username" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            User.setFocusable(true);
            Off_On.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }
        else if(str_pass.matches(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please inter password" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Pass.setFocusable(true);
            Off_On.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }
        else if(arg1==true)
        {
            Boolean s=false;
            s=Internet_state();
            if(!s)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please check internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Off_On.setChecked(false);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(MainActivity.this);
                if (intent != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } 

            }

        }
    }


};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prepare(Context) method returns null, since VPN application is already prepared.

> Prepare to establish a VPN connection. This method returns null if the VPN application is already prepared or if the user has previously consented to the VPN application. Otherwise, it returns an Intent to a system activity

Check out the steps to follow if VPN app is already ready: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html#prepare(android.content.Context))